# How to delete Music Creation?

Tags: storage, garageband

I followed the guidelines [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8163856) by doing the following:

1) Delete the GarageBand app from the Applications folder

2) Check the ~/Library folder for these files:

```
/Library/Application Support/GarageBand/
/Library/Application Support/Logic/
/Library/Audio/Apple Loops/
```

None of which were on my computer.

My Storage still shows 2.6G is being used by Music Creation. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the root level /Library, not the User Library.

Comment: I had no idea ~/Library and /Library were different things! Thanks. I found the first two directories, but not the third.

Comment: The slash symbol at the start of a filepath means "from the top". So /Applications is where your apps are. The ~/ symbols mean "within the user home". If a file path starts without any symbols, then it's relative to the current location.